# Unable to use Dotnet build with arguments using variables in tasks.json in vscode

Tags: .net-core, vscode-tasks, dotnet-cli

Unable to get dotnet build work using variables for build arguments

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "variables": {
        "outputDirectory": "/home/user/TestBuild/bin/${workspaceFolderBasename}",
        "projFilePath": "${workspaceFolder}/src/Trial1/Trial1.csproj"
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "shell",
            "linux": {
                "args": [
                    "build",
                    "${projFilePath}",
                    "-o",
                    "${outputDirectory}",
                    "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                    "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
                ]
            },
            "windows": {
                "args": [
                    "build",
                    "${projFilePath}",
                    "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                    "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
                ]
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "publish",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "shell",
            "args": [
                "publish",
                "{projFilePath}",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
    ]
}
```

Here is the output i get

Executing task: dotnet build ${projFilePath} -o ${outputDirectory} /property:GenerateFullPaths=true /consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary

Required argument missing for option: -o

- The terminal process "/usr/bin/bash '-c', 'dotnet build ${projFilePath} -o ${outputDirectory} /property:GenerateFullPaths=true /consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary'" terminated with exit code: 1

Can anyone please point where I'm going wrong with the JSON file?